# Fitting Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process in Python

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Hi~ I am wondering that are there some packages in python for the users to fit an OU process? I know that we can convert this problem into a regression problem or an AR(1) fitting problem and back out the parameters. Basically, it is posted on this link.
https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Calibrating-the-Ornstein.pdf

However, in some situation, the parameters in the regression problem are negative and can not compute log of it? Are there some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but just to let others find an answer: There is one package I was able to find, SdePy:

https://sdepy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1.2/generated/sdepy.ornstein_uhlenbeck_process.html